# Vários includes é ruim para performance?

Tags: php, include

Se eu utilizar muitos `includes` na minha página vai deixar ela mais lenta ou coisa do tipo?

Comment: A resposta é muito ampla, depende mais de o que você está incluindo do que da quantidade de *includes*. Pode ser que você faça um *include* que deixe uma aplçicação mais lenta que fazendo 15 *includes* diferentes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O *include* não deixa a página mais lenta, mas sim o conteúdo do arquivo que será incluído.

A performance depende do conteúdo do seu ficheiro que será incluído, por exemplo, muitos ciclos FOR fazem o script ficar mais lento, uma conexão com o banco de dados com uma *query* mal construía, etc...

O melhor seria procurar como melhorar a performance do seu script php, melhores práticas de desenvolvimento, etc...

Apenas a função *include* não irá afetar o desempenho. Agora se comparar um ***require()*** com um ***include()*** sim, o *require* é mais lento em relação ao *include*.

Utilize caminhos absolutos ao chamar os arquivos, assim o php não irá precisar analisar o `include_path`.

Deixo aqui alguns exemplos de boas práticas para você que está iniciando:

1. O [manual](http://php.net/) do php será o seu melhor amigo e vai responder (quase) todas as suas dúvidas.
2. Procure sobre práticas de *DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself)* e *KISS(Keep It Simple Stupid)*, ou seja, não repita código e mantenha tudo estupidamente simples.
3. Beleza não é fundamental, mas um código bem organizado facilita e muito a manutenção do sistema.
4. Utilize comentários, mas remova-os na versão utilizada em produção, comentários são bem vindos mas deixam os arqueis mais pesados (o próximo item completa este)
5. Minificar os arquivos pode ser uma boa solução, uma vez que os espaços e comentários serão removidos e algumas variáveis modificadas para melhorar a performance e diminuir o peso do ficheiro (no caso do *javascript*, menos tráfego).

Comment: Só faltou falar do Autoload ;)

Comment: Apenas um comentário, em todos testes que fiz o `require` e o `include` tem praticamente o mesmo desempenho, a única coisa que mudou é se o arquivo incluído for inacessível, no caso do `include` emite apenas uma notificação no erros, já no `require` ele finaliza a execução se tal arquivo for inacessível. Talvez o `require` só faça alguma diferença com o `include` em caso de performance se você tentar incluir mais de 100 arquivos (só teoria), em caso de importação de bibliotecas importantes sempre faço o uso de `require_once`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento então, "praticamente" indica uma diferença, embora pouca. Como expliquei acima, incluir 1 script mal confeccionado pode ser mais lento que inserir 100 includes com performance adequada.

Comment: Desculpe parecer estar discordando, mas eu vejo assim, se um script usando "include" é mal confeccionado, então ele vai ser ruim sem include ou com include, não é este o fator que diferencia. Não estou querendo contraria-lo, só digo que as vezes nem existe diferença. require e include não são funções, a única diferença deles é o tipo de erro que irá emitir, já se comparar `include` com `include_once` ou `require` com `require_once` então eu concordaria contigo (apesar que a diferença é insignificante). Até mais :)

Comment: Minificar arquivos não acho que seja uma boa prática tendo em vista que um projeto em PHP tem muitos arquivos código fonte, logo o trabalho de faze-lo será para um resultado totalmente irrisório em relação ao mesmo.

Comment: @FabioWilliamConceição para isso existe ferramentas que auxiliam na tarefa, por exemplo, o [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). Nos meus projetos para minificar aquivos de CSS e JS que serão enviados para produção, tenho o Gulp configurado e basta um comando para tudo ficar prontinho para produção, incluindo alterar as referências nos respectivos ficheiros.

Answer (score 5):

Quando se faz um include/require você, obviamente, tem como intenção incluir/requerer um recurso de outro arquivo externo, seja(m) ele(s) local(is) ou remoto(s). Esse(s) arquivo(s) está(ão) armazenado(s) num disco que, para ser(em) lido(s), depende(m) do sistema de arquivos que, por si só, é lento por definição.

Com esse pequeno parecer você já sabe que **sim**, usar muitos includes/requires é ruim para performance.

Mas existe outro fator bem significativo contra o fracionamento em múltiplos arquivos que é a interpretação do código escrito. Se você incluir 15 arquivos num único a ser acessado por dada Requisição, o interpretador vai "ler" e interpretar todos os *tokens* e analisar a sintaxe de 15 arquivos **antes** de permitir ao servidor enviar uma resposta como *output* pro browser.

Isso não só aumenta o tempo entre uma requisição e outra como também torna qualquer depuração de erro numa tarefa hercúlea para o desenvolvedor.

Comment: Será que o PHP realmente lê e compila o arquivo PHP cada vez que ele é requisitado? Eu realmente acredito que deve haver algum sistema de *cache* para otimizar isto.

Comment: Se não me falha a memória, até a versão 5.4 todo caching deveria ser feito pelo programador, fosse com a APC ou com outro engine. A partir do PHP 5.5 a APC tornou-se obsoleta PARA O PHP 5.5, já que a partir dessa versão o tipo de cahing que a APC proporcionava é feito de forma nativa.

Comment: Eu deixei uma resposta para você abaixo, espero que possa ajuda-lo na sua dúvida.

Answer (score 4):

Não há diferença entre tu escrever, por exemplo, 15 linhas de código em um arquivo ou jogar 5 dessas linhas para outra arquivo PHP e dar um include nele.

Em alguns casos tu vai querer usar `include_once` para garantir que o mesmo arquivo não seja incluído 2 (ou mais) vezes ([veja](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include-once.php)).

Comment: Na real há uma diferença sim, pois quando você dá include em um arquivo você trás todo aquele codigo fonte que está nele para o arquivo de origem, então logo caso você não vá usar nem 1/3 daquilo o interpretado vai compilar da mesma forma, logo perdendo desempenho.

Nesse caso é melhor usar classes e trabalhar apenas com as instâncias e depois exclui-las caso não vá usa-las mais.

Answer (score 1):

Um include pode atrapalhar a perfomance porque você pode fazer includes de arquivos desnecessários em momentos do código que você nem usará.

O orientado é estudar bem o seu tipo de sistema e caso você tenha variaveis em comum com valores solidos usa-las como constantes (caso o valor seja imutável).

Mas se você tem variaveis / metodos em comum com valores mutaveis, crie classes e herde-as (ou estende-as) assim você pode simplesmente repassar os valores que serão manipulados por referência e / ou parâmetro, mas isso vai depender muito do tipo de sistema e do tipo de arquitetura que você está adotando para desenvolvimento.

Sempre procure estudar patterns de projetos e gerenciamento de código, assim com o tempo você sempre estará fazendo códigos mais robustos e menos voluveis e limpos que ao longo da sua carreira você terá uma boa biblioteca pronta de códigos para utilizar em projetos posteriores.