# Unir arquivos PHP em um só aumenta a performance?

Tags: php, arquivo, desempenho

Eu tenho a impressão que, toda vez que executo o comando `dump-autoload` para gerar o autoload  das classes via `composer`, um arquivo `bootstrap/compiled.php` é criado.

Dentro dele, parece haver um emaranhado de classes e namespaces (é como se tivessem unidos vários arquivos em um só).

Gerar um código PHP em que as classes utilizadas estão no mesmo arquivo seria "mais rápido" do que ter elas "espalhadas" pelos diretórios?

Comment: O arquivo `compiled.php` pode deixar a aplicação lenta ? Porque quando se instala o Laravel 5 pede-se para deletar o arquivo. **Once installed, you should upgrade to the latest packages. First, remove `{directory}/vendor/compiled.php` file then change your current directory to `{directory}` and issue composer update command.**

Comment: @Zooboomafoo nesse caso é pedido para excluir esse arquivo porque a classe source estará diferente do que está no compiled. Ele geralmente já é excluído, mas as vezes pode ocorrer algum problema.

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15005/250

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Sim, aumenta. E daí?

Primeiro, será um aumento mínimo. Irrelevante na maioria dos casos, se não todos. O ganho será só na carga. E provavelmente você não conseguirá nem medir.

Provavelmente você não precisa ter esse ganho. E se precisar, tem muitas outras coisas mais importantes para melhorar a performance.

Esqueça isso, pense na organização.

É óbvio que quanto menos acesso a disco, melhor. Porém se isso é usado pouco não faz diferença, se é usado muito já estará no cache do sistema operacional e a diferença será bem próxima de zero.

Você terá melhor benefício se usar um [sistema de cache de código padrão da linguagem](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) ou [de terceiros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators).

Não sei exatamente o que faz isso que você citou mas provavelmente está tudo em um só arquivo porque não foi feito para um ser humano ler, não precisa estar organizado, então é mais fácil fazer assim. Ele não junta tudo por causa da performance.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Claro que não vou juntar tudo! mas a ideia seria bacana em um sistema onde algum comando geraria isso automaticamente. Na verdade, acho microotimização ridícula... E a pergunta foi mais curiosidade... rsrsrs

Comment: Eu entendi isso.

Comment: Complementando a resposta, uma boa leitura são os PSRs que são recomendações sobre organização do código que trazem benefícios mais relevantes do que o desempenho do código em si. (http://www.php-fig.org/psr/)

Comment: Uma coisa que não foi citada é que apesar de ter um ganho com a diminuição de leitura em disco, você poderá ter um uso excessivo de memória. Por exemplo, se você tiver 3 classes em um arquivo, as 3 classes serão carregadas em memória, quando se divide em vários arquivos e um autoload é usado, a classe só será carregada para a memória quando for utilizada. Ou seja o ganho de performance com a leitura em disco pode resultar em um uso muito alto de memória e sobrecarga no servidor caso o arquivo seja muito grande com muitas classes, sem falar no tempo de leitura desse arquivo.

Comment: Excelente resposta +1.... o mais importante é ter facilidade em dar manutenção no código... isso sim é a velocidade que importa: A velocidade no atendimento a novas demandas do seu cliente.

Answer (score 22):

> Gerar um código PHP em que as classes utilizadas estão no mesmo
>   arquivo seria "mais rápido" do que ter elas "espalhadas" pelos
>   diretórios?

Teoricamente executar um único arquivo diminui o acesso ao disco, que não precisa buscar por diversos outros arquivos.

Porém se preocupar com isso pode ser uma otimização precoce, pois ao utilizar o `OpCache`, que vem por padrão a partir do `PHP 5.5+`, porém desativado, é feito um cache dos arquivos na memória e o gargalo de I/O já morre ai.

> Eu tenho a impressão que, em toda vez que executo o comando
>   dump-autoload para gerar o autoload das classes via composer, um
>   arquivo bootstrap/compiled.php é criado.

O Composer não gera o arquivo `compiled.php` ao executar `dump-autoload`, esse comando somente gera novamente os *autoloaders* da pasta `vendor\composer` a partir do que está configurado no `composer.json` do projeto.

Você deve estar confundindo esse arquivo com o `php artisan otimize` do Laravel, que usa [uma biblioteca para gerar esse arquivo compilado automaticamente](https://github.com/ClassPreloader/ClassPreloader) para juntar classes do framework, arquivo esse que pode [trazer mais problemas do que ajudar](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20compiled.php).

Resumindo: não se preocupe com isso. Em ambientes de produção habilite o OpCache do PHP e seja feliz.

Mais sobre o OpCache você [pode ler aqui<sup>en</sup>](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-opcache/).

Comment: Se pudesse, dava +2, por causa do tal do `OpCache` :)

Comment: Ah, e o comando pra criar esse arquivo `compiled.php` existe :)

Answer (score 4):

Sim, aumenta a performance, mas é irrisória o resultado final, na verdade não vale nem a pena o trabalho.

Pois deve-se lembrar que futuramente necessitar tirar a minificação que você fez no código, e como qualquer sistema PHP é mais de 1 arquivo, você terá muito trabalho para uma diferença de performance irrisória como eu disse anteriormente.

Caso você queira entender melhor como funciona a performance do PHP em seus sistemas, tenta estudar sobre como funciona a alocação de memória e os tipos de variáveis, assim você pode começar a codificar e tipificar (mesmo que não seja uma prática comum no PHP) as suas variáveis e assim evitar que uma variável tenha uma alocação maior que deveria na memória.

Comment: Na verdade, se eu fosse minificar o código, eu utilizaria uma ferramenta que fosse fazer isso numa fonte original. Ou seja, minificar não seria o problema. Só que com as outras respostas, acabei ficando convencido que realmente não vale a pena fazer essa minificação. Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: Ah sim, tem vários gerados que faz isso para você, mas lembre-se que teria que fazer arquivo à arquivo, você poderia usar algum plugin no sublime text que faz isso (ou desenvolve-lo).

Comment: Mas como eu falei, não vale a pena, pois isso no final das contas não faz nenhuma diferença na sua aplicação.