# Um arquivo com várias funções OU vários arquivos com uma função?

Tags: php, include, funções

No escopo do meu projeto uso `include("funcoes.php")`, dentro desse arquivo tem todas as funções que uso em diferentes partes do projeto, não uso todas as funções todo tempo.

Então uma dúvida!

Pro sistema seria mais vantajoso, com relação a desempenho, usar só esse include e deixar todas funções lá, ou fazer vários arquivos, onde cada um tenha sua função determinada, e conforme a necessidade do uso da função utilizar o `include("nome.funcao.php")`, ou o ganho não seria tão vantajoso, sendo assim seria mais fácil manter um arquivo único e centralizar tudo em um mesmo escopo!

Minha dúvida é pelo seguinte.
Nesse arquivo tenho umas 30 funções, funções simples até as mais complexas, só que não utilizo as 30 o tempo todo, e o arquivo `include("funcoes.php")` é incluído no topo de todas as páginas, então supondo que eu utilize 5 funções, as outras 25 foram carregadas "atoa".

Comment: relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203510/um-arquivo-com-v%C3%A1rias-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ou-v%C3%A1rios-arquivos-com-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o (não quero dizer que é uma solução)

Comment: relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74647/unir-arquivos-php-em-um-s%C3%B3-aumenta-a-performance

Comment: @DanielOmine dei uma lida! Já deu uma ajuda!

Comment: Eu criaria um arquivo para cada função...fica mais leve e claro o projeto...

Comment: Acredito que se não for um arquivo absurdamente grande não fará diferença, isso você só vai perceber testando, é muito relativo, porém uma idéia pode ser categorizar essas funções, por exemplo, um arquivo para funções relacionadas a datas e horários, outro para strings e etc... dessa forma você consegue um meio termo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesta quantidade de funções, isto é **irrelevante**.

Dificilmente você encontrará *um arquivo por função* em sistemas antigos que utilizavam esta estrutura que hoje é considerada improdutiva, a não ser que você esteja fazendo algo bem simples ou um sistema embarcado.

Devemos privilegiar a escrita moderna, aproveitando a orientação a objetos que ficou robusta nos últimos anos e usar o autoload de objetos em *Namespaces*, o que irá carregar somente o que for chamado.

Answer (score 1):

Criar um arquivo para cada função só é relevante caso sejam funções muito extensas, caso sejam funções relativamente curtas a diferença vai ser mínima e talvez imperceptível. 
Portanto, se preferir fazer tudo em um arquivo faça se preferir em vários faça em vários.